# Can a Xiaomi / MIUI phone bet set to use dd/mm date format?

Tags: settings, localization, xiaomi, miui

I have a Redmi 4A that I bought while in China a few months ago.

It works great in English but seems to only offer a choice of only 12- vs. 24-hour time format and American date format, mm/dd/yyyy.

For all English speakers who aren't American this format is very confusing. All my other devices let me change to dd/mm/yyyy format. But so far I can't find a way to do this on my phone.

Android version is 6.0.1 MMB29M and MIUI version is 8.5.4.0(MCCCNED)

Answer (score 2):

It's less Xiaomi than Android 6, which eliminated the corresponding setting from the settings pages unfortunately. The argument is obviously that those formats are bound to the region, and thus shall be chosen by the language you pick (English/US vs. English/UK,NZ,whatever).

What they obviously forgot is that the number of combinations is limited. No way to chose e.g. English/DE that way, to have English language with German date/time & number formats. Or that one user prefers the year in dates being 2 digit while another wants 4… I was looking for a better solution for weeks, but couldn't find it.

Also see: [How to change date and time format on Marshmallow?](/q/135743/16575)